# how can i Activation selinux?

Tags: kernel, root, selinux

i use `uname -r` to know the version of the kernel and this is the result **5.8.0-50-generic**

and try to know some information about SELinux by this command  `grep -i SELinux /boot/config-5.8.0-`

and this is the result **grep: /boot/config-5.8.0-: No such file or directory**
can anyone tell me where is the problem? and how can solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you did not use the correct filename.

The system told you that: `No such file or directory`

```
WRONG:   root@ubuntu:/# grep -i selinux /boot/config-5.8.0-
CORRECT: root@ubuntu:/# grep -i selinux /boot/config-5.8.0-50-generic
```

Comment: how can i find the correct filename?

Comment: You  already have the correct filename. You didn't use it. User typo.